# How to convert airtable curl POST command to c# or vb.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, curl, airtable

I am having a hard time adding a record to airtable from my test .net app. I am able to read data fine, but I'm not sure if i'm formatting the data correctly or not adding something to header. Here's an example:

```
    Dim wHeader As WebHeaderCollection = New WebHeaderCollection()

    wHeader.Clear()
    wHeader.Add("Authorization: Bearer keynNkH2CywXXXXX")

    Dim sUrl As String = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appGajjD5tTMmyCC5/Logs"

    Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(sUrl), HttpWebRequest)

    wRequest.ContentType = "application/json" ' I don't know what your content type is
    wRequest.Headers = wHeader

    wRequest.Method = "POST"
    wRequest.Accept = "*/*"
    Dim myData = "{""fields"": {""AppName"": ""test2"", ""Action"": ""hlkj"", ""User"": ""lhkjnjn""}}"

    wRequest.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)

    Dim wResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(wRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim sResponse As String = ""

    Using srRead As New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream())
        sResponse = srRead.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show(sResponse)
```

The error I keep getting is "422 Unprocessable Entity".

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the same problem. Coded something similar to you, getting that error. Then tried to incorporate this: https://github.com/ngocnicholas/airtable.net
into my project, but get the same error.
In case you want to try to incorporate that client into your project, this is how to call it from vb:

```
 Protected Async Sub t2Async()
        Dim myFields As Fields = New Fields()
        myFields.AddField("Name", "Some value")
        Dim myAirtableBase As AirtableBase = New AirtableBase(appKey, baseId)
        Dim myTask As Task(Of AirtableCreateUpdateReplaceRecordResponse) = myAirtableBase.CreateRecord("Clients", myFields, False)
        Dim response = Await myTask
    End Sub
```

But as I said, it generates the same error. Let me know, if you figure something out...